# Why can't my constexpr function return a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constexpr

I found this piece of code doesn't work:

```
typedef int (*fp)(int a, int b);

constexpr fp addition()
{
    return [](int a, int b){ return a+b; };
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    fp fun = addition();
    std::cout << fun(2,2);
}
```

It gives me error

```
cexpr.cpp: In function 'constexpr int (* addition())(int, int)':
cexpr.cpp:5:43: error: call to non-constexpr function 'addition()::<lambda(int,
int)>::operator int (*)(int, int)() const'
```

Why is that? I'm not calling it here.

Direct approach works:

```
typedef int (*fp)(int a, int b);

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    fp fun = [](int a, int b){ return a+b; };
    std::cout << fun(2,2);
}
```

I'm using MinGW with g++ version 4.7.2.

Comment: The implicit conversion to function pointers isn't `constexpr` apparently.

Comment: @Pubby changing it to `return static_cast<fp>([](int a, int b){ return a+b; });`, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Pubby: That is not a problem. `constexpr int f(int a) { return a; }` is absolutely fine!

Comment: The conversion function? Yes, you _are_ calling it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function `fp()` does not return a literal type, therefore it cannot be a *constexpr function*:

> From 7.1.5: "The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - it shall not be virtual (10.3);
> - **its return type shall be a literal type**;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - its function-body shall be = delete, = default, **or a compound-statement that contains only**
>
>   - null statements,
>   - static_assert-declarations
>   - typedef declarations and alias-declarations that do not define classes or enumerations,
>   - using-declarations,
>   - using-directives,
>   - **and exactly one return statement**;"

I do not think there is any bug here, and especially nothing related to lambdas as mentioned in an earlier answer: variables simply cannot be declared inside of a *constexpr function*.

Comment: But according to [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417719/Constants-and-Constant-Expressions-in-Cplusplus11) (i don't have a copy of the C++11 standard) pointer type is a literal type.

Comment: @milleniumbug: (sorry, I am editing this comment because the previous version was badly formatted): from what I understand, the standard defines nullptr as the only pointer-literal (2.14.7) "The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. [...]"

Comment: btw you can download the working draft of the standard from this link:

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf

Comment: Oh well - A literal constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, but not pointer type (after
conversions as required by the context). (5.19.4)

Comment: BTW thanks for the link - this is even newer than what I found several months ago. I thought after the C++11 has been released, there won't be any updates. Silly me ;)

Comment: You're welcome, anyway you will always find the link to the current working draft on the official page of ISO C++ (http://www.isocpp.org): it's on the top-left corner, right below Bjarne's picture :)

Answer (score 7):

According to N3376 working draft of the standard section 5.19 [expr.const]:

> Certain contexts require expressions that satisfy additional
>   requirements as detailed in this sub-clause; other contexts have
>   diﬀerent semantics depending on whether or not an expression satisﬁes
>   these requirements. Expressions that satisfy these requirements are
>   called constant expressions. [ Note: Constant expressions can be
>   evaluated during translation.— end note ]

It goes on to say:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   (3.2), but subexpressions of logical AND (5.14), logical OR (5.15),
>   and conditional (5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not
>   considered [ Note: An overloaded operator invokes a function.— end
>   note ]:

Which lists under it:

> — a lambda-expression (5.1.2);

So while I don't know enough standardese, I believe this says that a constexpr shouldn't have a lambda expression inside.

Comment: I believe "constant expression" and "constexpr functions" are two different things. The requirements for a "constexpr function" in the standard are listed under 7.1.5 (point 3), and this doesn't mention that the body of a "constexpr function" must be a "constant expression". The latter probably allows for more than the former (but I admit I do not speak standardese either).

Comment: @AndyProwl I am unsure because all the example code from the section uses `constexpr` as a measure of "okay" or "not". I did end up looking further into it though and it lists the requirements for a `constexpr` function at around section 7.1.5 point 3 like you say so.

Comment: I believe it does so to show that a "constexpr variable" can be initialized by invoking a "constexpr function" and that makes it a valid "constant expression", but that does not specify what can and cannot be part of the body of a "constexpr function"

Answer (score 6):

The error message gcc gave you was precise and correct:

> error: call to non-constexpr function 'addition()::
>                <lambda(int,int)>::
>                **operator int (*)(int, int)() const**'

I've reformatted it a bit and added emphasis. By coercing the lambda to a function pointer, you're implicitly calling the automatically-created conversion function from lambda to `pointer to function of type "auto (int, int)->int"`, which is not a constexpr function because the automatically-created conversion function is not declared `constexpr` (and the standard doesn't require it to be).

Comment: "It's too late" - doesn't matter. The more answers, the better for me ;) Have an upvote.

Comment: Now that I see it, this is completely obvious, but wasn't when I was asking. Probably I saw here `operator int (int, int)() const` instead and was confused. What You See Is Not Always What You Want To See indeed.